# ¿Debo cambiar la estructura de mi proyecto Akka para integrar Play?

Tags: scala

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto Akka, sacando provecho del modelo de actores. Ahora querría exponer alguna de la lógica de negocio como servicios REST y estoy barajando utilizar Play Framework (parece más sencillo) o Akka Http (más de bajo nivel).

De entrada optaría por Play 2.5 pero los proyectos Play tienen un layout definidos. Por ejemplo, la carpeta raíz para el código fuente es "/app". Para integrar Play en el proyecto Akka, ¿debería reorganizar el código para adaptarlo a Play o hay alguna forma sencilla de integrar Play sin tener que mover todo el código?

Answer (score 0):

quizás me equivoco, pero puedes intentar poniendo los actores en tu configuración global y desde play manipularlos.
Lo digo por esta respuesta que conseguí acá mismo....
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091615/how-to-create-a-global-variable-with-play-framework-2-0

Espero sea de tu ayuda, buen día.
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaGlobal

Comment: Los enlaces se deben usar para soportar tu respuesta. No está mal que los incluyas, pero lo mejor sería que trajeras/tradujeras la parte relevante aquí. Tal y como está ahora, si por cualquier motivo se rompen los enlace (que ocurre a menudo), tu respuesta dejará de ser válida y no tendrá sentido.

Comment: Gracias, lo tomaré en cuenta.